# Win10 Anniversary + Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot destroyed after running "apt-get upgrade" && "apt-get update"

Tags: windows-10, boot, multi-boot, grub2, ubuntu-16.04

I have a 2013 Samsung ATIV Book 6 (I think NP680Z5E-X01US) laptop. Original OS was Win8.

While I keep Windows around for some entertainment stuff I created a partition for a Linux distro (Ubuntu 14.04).

Since then I upgraded to Windows 10 (incl. all updates such as Anniversary) and recently upgraded Ubuntu to 16.04 when the prompt showed up.

Everything was fine until yesterday. I could run both systems and the normal GRUB menu would show up on boot, giving me the choice between Windows and Ubuntu.

I recently upgraded a lot of drivers for Windows including the dedicated video card (Radeon HD 8700M). Since then I used and rebooted Windows 10 multiple times for Windows updates.

Yesterday I switched to Ubuntu for some work. I ran `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` as I do from time to time. Everything went fine, no errors or anything like that.

When I wanted to boot into Windows 10 and restarted the PC, the "Minimal bash-like GRUB" screen popped up. Switching boot order to Windows 10 first, the system went into a long "Preparing automatic repair" mode which completed after 40 minutes.

The result was a black screen with cursor, seemingly a known Windows 10 issue which can be circumvented by blindly entering your password or switching the display output (via `Win+P`). But both did not work. Nothing helped at all. Tried this multiple times.

After googling around to understand what was happening I decided to run `boot-repair` via USB-Live Ubuntu + Terminal. After getting an error "GPT detected. [...]" and fixing it by creating another 5MB ext4 partition with GParted to give it the `bios_grub` flag, `boot-repair` successfully completed. Yay?

On reboot ... nothing changed. Boot repair had no effect at all. What can I do now? I am out of approaches.

Answer (score 0):

1. Repair your Windows. Boot from any Live DVD and delete all the System small System Partitions and such. Just leave your Linux and the Windows Partition on your HDD.
2. Boot from the Windows DVD and go select Automatic Repair. Your computer will likely need to do Automatic Repair 3 times before your are able to boot into Windows again.
3. When Windows is confirmed working, get yourself a copy of Rescatux (http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/) and boot from it.
4. Install the Bootloader on your HardDrive and let Rescatux repair Grub (or build Grub menu)
5. Done

Comment: In my case this did not work - automatic repair in Windows always failed to black screen. I ended up wiping the entire HDD. I reinstalled both Win10 and Ubuntu, works flawless now. Of course data loss is a big issue with that approach but I recovered my machine from being bricked. Tried dozens of solutions before, none got me past automatic repair failure in Windows.